# Add permission boundaries to the stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-roles, aws-permissions

When I deploy a CDK stack - it creates several roles, both explicitly e.g. via `iam.Role` construct, and implicitly e.g. when roles are created internally by Level 2 constructs.

Is there a way to attach an existing permission boundary to all the roles being created by the stack - both explicit and implicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [through aspects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/aspects.html).

You can add the following in `bin/app.ts` (the file might be named differently):

```
class ConfigurePermissionBoundary implements IAspect {
  visit(node: IConstruct): void {
    if (node instanceof CfnRole) {
      const stack1 = Stack.of(node);
      let policy = stack1.node.tryFindChild('GlobalPermissionBoundaryPolicy') as ManagedPolicy | undefined

      if (!policy) {
        policy = new ManagedPolicy(stack1, 'GlobalPermissionBoundaryPolicy', {
          statements: [new PolicyStatement({
            effect: Effect.DENY,
            actions: ['sts:*'],
            resources: ['*']
          })]
        })
      }

      node.permissionsBoundary = policy.managedPolicyArn
    }
  }
}

Aspects.of(app).add(new ConfigurePermissionBoundary())
```

Please note that we're adding a managed policy `GlobalPermissionBoundaryPolicy` that defines the permission boundary once.
Also, the aspect handles both `new iam.Role()` as well as any `new CfnRole()` defined by your or library code.